# cant append child nodes to a parent node( VBA-XML)

Tags: xml, vba, appendchild

Here is my VBA code where I am modifying an XML with excel datasheet. 
xml is here : https://www.jiocloud.com/s/?t=SzqFJhEABfsTQfZW&s=a2

```
function fnUpdateXMLByTags()
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wrsht As Worksheet


Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wrsht = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
wrsht.Activate

Dim oXMLFile As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set oXMLFile = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
oXMLFile.async = False
oXMLFile.validateOnParse = False
XMLFileName = "Z:\IPC\IPC1752A_WK-200264-000 - Copy (2).xml"
XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:d='http://webstds.ipc.org/175x/2.0'"
oXMLFile.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces

For i = 3 To 5
  If Not IsEmpty(mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)) Then

        PartID = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
        PartName = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value
        MaterialName = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value
        MassAmount = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value
        MassUnit = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & i).Value
        Path = "D:\New folder\" & PartID & ".xml"

        If oXMLFile.Load(XMLFileName) Then

            Set PartIDNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//@itemNumber")
            Set PartNameNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//@itemName")
            Set MaterialNameNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//@name")
            Set MassAmountNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//@value")
            Set MassUnitNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//@UOM")
            PartIDNodes(0).NodeValue = Part_ID
            PartNameNodes(0).NodeValue = PartName
            MaterialNameNodes(5).NodeValue = MaterialName
            MassAmountNodes(1).NodeValue = MassAmount
            MassUnitNodes(1).NodeValue = MassUnit

        End If

    Else:
        If IsEmpty(mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i)) Then
            Substancename = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value
            CASNumber = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & i).Value
            SubAmount = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & i).Value
           Set SubstanceCategoryNode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//d:SubstanceCategory")
           Set Substancenode = oXMLFile.createElement("d:Substance")
           Substancenode.Text = "<SubstanceID identity="" authority=""/> <Amount value="" UOM=""/> "
           SubstanceCategoryNode.appendChild (Substancenode)
             "throwwin error here"

           oXMLFile.Save Path
         End If


End If


Next i

End Function
```

when I append a child to parent it throws "Object doesn't support this property or method"

please suggest where I am wrong.is there is any other way to append a child node to a parent node

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the type of SubstanceCategoryNode is IXMLDOMSelection. It is a selection, which is just a view of the XML tree. To build/append elements, I'd actually create an element, like the Substancenode variable above...

```
Set SubstanceCategoryNode = oXMLFile.createElement("d:SubstanceCategory")
```

... or so

Use the watch window/TypeName() function

Comment: yes, you are right @thomasM, its a selection so it cant append it.

Comment: Your answer and the suggestion... Teach a Man to Fish, Rather Than Give Fish! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. The original source had four "Substance" nodes sitting under substance category.

[image: Nodes]

Before:

[image: Before]

You can append a child node i.e. adding another Substance node (I am guessing?)
and an easy way is to clone an existing and then change its properties e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim xml As String, doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xml = [A1].Text
    Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    If Not doc.LoadXML(xml) Then
        Err.Raise doc.parseError.ErrorCode, , doc.parseError.reason
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim node As IXMLDOMElement, newNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Set node = doc.DocumentElement.LastChild.ChildNodes(1).FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(1) '<== MaterialInfo > HomogeneousMaterialList>HomogeneousMaterial>SubstanceCategoryList > SubstanceCategoryListID>SubstanceCategory

   Set newNode = node.appendChild(node.LastChild.CloneNode(True))

   'Adjust newNode properties
    Stop
End Sub
```

After:

[image: Cloned node appended]

Comment: Hello, @qharr Thanks for answering. Sorry for the late response. with your help and suggestion  I did solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

FYI I created another XML with only substance category and imported a node from there using.

Set Substancenode = oXMLFile.importNode(oXMLFile2.DocumentElement.LastChild, True)

Comment: that's the problem. I am not able to upvote yet. haven't reached that threshold. yes as you suggested I have posted it as an answer

Comment: You'll get there!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Instead of

```
Set SubstanceCategoryNode = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//d:SubstanceCategory")
```

I have to use this.

```
Set SubstanceCategoryNode = oXMLFile.SelectsingleNode("//d:SubstanceCategory")
```

from SelectNodes to selectsinglenode.

Thanks to both @qharr and @ThomasMX for support.

Comment: Does this add a node? Or select the first node? Time for some homework for me....

Comment: It selects the node(the only node). Maybe I can share complete code to you (all my work) if you need.

Comment: Lol. Because your question was how to append a node not select. Select was the other question I remember answering and append was the one I answered here. It is confusing to give an answer that actually isn't to the question as posed.

Comment: I think that you should edit this wrong auto-answer...  as ThomasMX said, SelectNodes or SelectSingleNode both return a IXMLDOMSelection, and we cannot do "verbs" with them, like Add, Append, Delete... U need to do what QHar said (convoluted for me...) or what ThomasMX said: first do a `Set SubstanceCategoryNode = oXMLFile.createElement("d:SubstanceCategory")`  and after you can Append, Add, InsertBefore; for example: `Set newNode = node.appendChild(SubstanceCategoryNode) `  [Here is a very easy and complete tutorial](http://www.functionx.com/vbaccess/Lesson63.htm)